# How do I make the derivatives in a vector have a bigger font size and in addition, how do I center my equations?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, fontsize

[image]

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\title{AE498 SDO - HW1}
\nonstopmode
%\usepackage[utf-8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage[figurename=Figure]{caption}
\usepackage{float}    % For tables and other floats
\usepackage{verbatim} % For comments and other
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}% For math
\usepackage{amssymb}  % For more math
\usepackage{fullpage} % Set margins and place page numbers at bottom center
\usepackage{paralist} % paragraph spacing
\usepackage{listings} % For source code
\usepackage{subfig}   % For subfigures
%\usepackage{physics}  % for simplified dv, and 
\usepackage{enumitem} % useful for itemization
\usepackage{siunitx}  % standardization of si units 


\begin{align*}
\nabla \theta &= \begin{pmatrix} \pdv{\theta}{R}\\[6pt] \pdv{\theta}{H}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 4\pi R+2\pi H\\ 2\pi R\end{pmatrix}\\[6pt] 
\nabla h &= \begin{pmatrix} \pdv{h}{R}\\[6pt] \pdv{h}{H}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2(0.001)}{\pi R^3}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}


Equation (1) yields 2 equations and equation (2) yields 1 equation. Therefore we have 3 equations to solve for 3 unknowns ($R, H,\lambda$).

\begin{align*}
4\pi R+2\pi H\ &= \lambda \frac{0.002}{\pi R^3} \\[6pt]
2\pi R&= \lambda,\qquad R=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} \\[6pt]
h(R,H)&=H-\frac{0.001}{\pi R^2} =0, \qquad H=\frac{0.004\pi}{ \lambda^2} \\[6pt]
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question so that the code will compile. That way people can reproduce your image and try to help. Centred how? They are centred, aren't they?

Comment: Hi, thank for your willingness to help! So I kind of want my second block of equations to be aligned about equal sign and centered wrt to the page like the first block of equations. Notice how the equations look like a downward staircase. I have a suspicion its because I used \qquad as horizontal spacing. If there is anyway to ease this eyesore, please let me know!

Comment: There is no unique = sign in the lower block. And if you write `\displaystyle` before the `\pdv` commands, the fractions become larger.

Comment: Use `\dfrac{\partial\theta}{\partial R}` instead of `\pdv{\theta}{R}`, etc to typeset the partial derivative terms inside the column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

for comparison purposes i increase size of your vector only in the firs equation. for this i use `\displaystyle` before `pdv`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\title{AE498 SDO - HW1}
\nonstopmode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% <-- corrected
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage[figurename=Figure]{caption}
\usepackage{float}    % For tables and other floats
\usepackage{verbatim} % For comments and other
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}% For math
\usepackage{amssymb}  % For more math
\usepackage{fullpage} % Set margins and place page numbers at bottom center
\usepackage{paralist} % paragraph spacing
\usepackage{listings} % For source code
\usepackage{subfig}   % For subfigures
%\usepackage{physics}  % for simplified dv, and  <-- it is sufficient to load ones
\usepackage{enumitem} % useful for itemization
\usepackage{siunitx}  % standardization of si units

 \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\nabla\theta    & = \begin{pmatrix}
                        \displaystyle\pdv{\theta}{R}\\[6pt] % corrected size by \displaystyle
                        \displaystyle\pdv{\theta}{H}        % corrected size
                    \end{pmatrix}
                  = \begin{pmatrix}
                    4\pi R+2\pi H\\
                    2\pi R\end{pmatrix}         \\[6pt]
\nabla h        & = \begin{pmatrix}
                        \pdv{h}{R}\\[6pt]                   % not corrected
                        \pdv{h}{H}                          % not corrected
                    \end{pmatrix}
                  = \begin{pmatrix}
                        \dfrac{2(0.001)}{\pi R^3}\\
                        1
                    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Equation (1) yields 2 equations and equation (2) yields 1 equation. Therefore we have 3 equations to solve for 3 unknowns ($R, H,\lambda$).
\begin{gather*}
4\pi R+2\pi H 
    = \lambda \frac{0.002}{\pi R^3}             \\
2\pi R
    = \lambda,\quad R=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}     \\
h(R,H)
    = H-\frac{0.001}{\pi R^2} =0, \quad H=\frac{0.004\pi}{ \lambda^2}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense. How do you propose I center the second block of equations instead of it being a downward staircase? Ideally they would all be aligned about the equal signs.

Comment: ups, on the second set i forgot. it is now aligned to equal sign. if this is not desired, than instead of `align` use `gather` and omit ampersands. i correct this in answer.

Comment: you are a superstar!

Comment: @DevanjithFonseka, really? :-)  if you will not receive beter answer, you can accept mine (by clicking on check mark ad its top left side) :-)

Comment: didn't know what that mark stood for but the check mark is yours!